# Is it possible to export POINT and LINE in the same DXF from POSTGRESQL using OGR2OGR?

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, dxf, osgeo4w

I have two tables in a pg database. One with annotations/points and one with linestrings.
I would like to export both of them to the same dxf file with ogr2ogr. Is it possible at all somehow?
I have managed to export the lines based on [this article](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190159/export-to-dxf-from-postgresql-using-ogr2ogr).
And the points as well based on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73406/exporting-postgis-geometry-point-as-label-text-to-dxf-or-dgn). I also checked the official [gdal documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html) but there are no examples for my problem.

The ogr2ogr commands:

```
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" dir\line_layer.dxf "PG:host=*** user=*** dbname=***" -sql "select the_geom from shcema.line_table"
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" dir\annot_layer.dxf "PG:host=*** user=*** dbname=***" -sql "select the_geom, ogr_style from shcema.annot_table"
```

The *ogr_style* column contains data like this: `"LABEL(f:""Times New Roman"",s:12pt,t:Sz 5)"`

**So my question is:** Is it somehow possible to export from these two different sources to the same dxf file?
(I am using GDAL 3.0.4.)

Comment: Points and lines can be written into same DXF but they must come from one OGR datasource as documented `Only one OGR layer can be used to create the output file (but many DXF layers can be created)`. You could combine lines and points into one layer in PostGIS but then you must add dummy OGR_STYLE field also for your line features.

Comment: I combined them and now on the dxf I can see the lines and the insertion points of the texts, but not the texts themselves. I  added `PEN(c:black)` to the ogr_stlye column for the lines. In the sql query i tried selecting everything/ only the geom/ the geom and the ogr_style/ the geom and the text but none of them worked as I hoped. Do you have any idea what am I missing?

Comment: I apologize but you have now more experience than I have about DXF and GDAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution and now I am answering my own question.
The geometry column must be *geometry* type, so it can store lines and points as well.
You can specify the display style in a column called *ogr_style*, based on the parameters shown [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html). Also if you add a column called *layer* you can specify a layer for the given record.

Note that you will get an error message, but the output will be just fine:

```
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ogr_style' not created.
```

Here is a sample of my postgresql table:

[image]